# entity framework 5 execute sql command insert and identity column

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to use SQL NEWID() keyword to generate a random Id for my primary key column

```
   using (var dc = new ExcelWebDBEntities())
    {
        dc.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(@"
            declare @id nvarchar(6) = substring(cast(NEWID() as nvarchar(max)),0,6);

            insert into Groups ([Id],[Name])
            values (@id,'TEST')

            select @id
        ");
    }
```

how do I get the generated id? Or would it be easier to just generate the unique id on c# side of things?

Comment: Just a tip. Using `NEWID` to generate primary keys leads to high fragmentation very quickly. I'd recommend using plain old `int` columns with `IDENTITY` instead.

Comment: but what if don't want users to be able to guess group ids like in a url

Comment: You could use a separate column for that, and a UNIQUEIDENTIFIER isn't a bad choice in that case. But making that your primary key means that *every* join will be slow due to the fragmented index. [More info here](http://www.nullskull.com/a/1504/why-guids-are-not-a-good-idea-for-sql-server-primary-keys.aspx).

Comment: thanks for the insight. If you make this an answer I will mark it.